# Jenkins Windows slave sometime hangs after second "Build on" step

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, debian, windows-server-2012-r2

I've a Windows Server 2012 R2 based Hyper-V Host, which contains a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM as a VPN using RRAS and another VM running Debian plus the Jenkins (latest version) master server. Using this VPN, a private hosted Windows Server 2012 R2 VM act as Jenkins slave using those VPN connection. For better distinction, call this one node1.

This is bascially working as expected, but there is a problem: Sometimes, when I start a buildjob on *node1*, it hangs. Only the first 2 steps (*Started through user XYZ* and *Build on slave node1 in workspace C:\jenkins* are shown in the log, then **nothing** happens. On the master, the *node1* is shown as online and is connected to the VPN.

Currently I start Jenkins using a windows task. Using this method, the above happens only sometimes. But as I configured the server, I tried to solve this in a cleaner way by registering Jenkins as Windows Service. As Windows Service, I had the same behavior: In the web panel *Node1* is shown as online, but when I start a job on it I only come to *Build on slave node1* and then it stops.

Normally the next step should be fetching the latest source code from my git repo. I already [had the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706756/jenkins-stop-after-build-at-slave) but now found out that it has something to do how Jenkins is started. But for me it seems very strange because running the slave as a Windows Service hasn't worked at least one time, and by running it as a Task it works most of the time.

I only found out that the problem also occurs when I start a job directly after *node1* boots. When I then cancel the hanging Job and start it again, it seems to work for a while.

Comment: Try to connect your slave via jnlp on CMD.exe, it might spit out some additional information, i.e. Exceptions thrown on the slave etc. Step 1-5 from [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Launch+Java+Web+Start+slave+agent+via+Windows+Scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

There are few options that I can think of them. According to [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service)

> If the slave is supposed to start desktop applications you have to
>   allow the service to interact with the desktop
>   (Action->Properties->Logon->Allow service to interact with desktop).

Another option can be that Windows services don't have the ability to [interact with the windows desktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653293(v=vs.85).aspx), meaning that some UI tests might no work as you expect. Do any of the steps may need interacting with the desktop (Windows GUI)?

Just for the sports how about to setup a temporary clean windows server to act as node2 (Jenkins slave) and to check if the problem is been reproduced?